# Has it been observed so far an object moving towards a BH along the trajectory of the polar astrophysical jet?

Tags: electromagnetism, black-holes, spacetime, relativistic-jets

**If we assume that the cause of the astrophysical jet is the magnetism of the BH than an object falling towards the BH in counterdirection of 'polar jet' emitions should not feel any strong deflection of its trajectory but has that kind of events been observed so far?** (I am asking this question as I am concerned only by a 'science-fiction' idea that there is a possibility of an effect slightly similar to 'frame dragging' of spacetime (in this special case 'frame casting' from the inside of the event horizon) that is the cause of the polar astrophysical jets as this logic does not go against the theory that nothing material can go faster than light as in this case the spacetime itself goes out from the BH and in that case this could affect the motion of the mentioned object....) Of course, this my speculation or idea could be wrong if there are observational proves that the astrophysical jets do not start from the inside of the event horizon...